# number of items to ship including each item of bundles products and taken into account refunded items?

Tags: magento

How can I get the number of items to ship including each item of bundles products and taken into account refunded items?

I tried to use this formula:
ordered-refunded-cancelled

This works fine with simple product, but not with simple products linked to a bundle product.

Let's take an example.
1 customer order this:
    Simple product A * 10
    Bundle product B * 10
    Product A
    product C

Customer cannot choose the quantity of product within the bundle, so it means there are 10 more A + 10 C.
product A can either be sold separately or as part of the bundle product B.

My customer asked for a report showing the quantity of each simple products per order, displayed separately to check his stock, so it shows for this order:
Product A * 20  <= note there are 20 as it is also part of the bundle
Product C * 10

That works well.
However, assuming I did a refund of 1 item of the standalone product A, and 3 items of the bundle

The order is now:
Simple product A * 9  (minus 1))
Bundle product B * 7  (minus 3)
---- Product A
---- product C

But The report shows
Product A * 18  (!! instead of  16)
Product C * 9 (!!instead of 7)

this is because the item object link to an order contains strange information.
With simple product not linked to bundle that's OK
for example with the independent product A I have:
ordered: 10
refunded: 1 <= (if I refund 3 I would have 3)

But with simple products linked to bundle, magento always put 1 in refunded whatever the quantity you refund!!
So I have this:
product A (linked to bundle)
ordered: 10
refunded: 1
while it should be :
ordered: 10
refunded: 3

and for product C linked to bundle I have the same:
ordered: 10
refunded: 1
while it should be :
ordered: 10
refunded: 3

so obviously I have wrong information.
It looks like this issue is only linked with bundle products having a configuration with items that the customer cannot choose the quantity of each item of the bundle (he can only choose the quantity of the bundle).
With other bundles where the user can choose the quantity of each item separately, then the information is correct.

so I am wondering how to solve this, and how to retrieve the right information, the right quantity, at the level of the item (not at the level of the bundle).

one option could be to retrieve the refunded quantity linked to the bundle and apply it to each item, but this is only valid with bundle where the user cannot change the quantity...
And I 'm not sure how to retrieve this

did you already face this? how would you do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it by doing a reverse of
\app\design\adminhtml\base\default\template\bundle\sales\order\view\items\renderer.phtml

This is the file used at the back office (order detail view) to show the list of ordered/refunded/invoiced items.

I can use the  canShowPriceInfo($item) method, if true then I can rely on the refunded value, otherwise I can't and I have to use the refuned value of the parent item!!

I put this in my code building a report with products to be shipped:

> ```
> $qtyRefunded=$orderItem->getQtyRefunded();> 
> if($orderItem->getParentItem() && !$this->canShowPriceInfo($orderItem)) $qtyRefunded=$orderItem->getParentItem()->getQtyRefunded();
> ```